# Why is it such a big deal in the USA if anyone touches you, ever so slightly?

Tags: united-states, privacy

Note: I'm not talking about Corona/whatever.

I've noticed, in numerous videos and other contexts, that Americans go "bananas" if somebody happens to physically touch them in public, or be on the verge of touching them. Granted, the context is usually a "confrontational" video where they have tricked somebody to meet up with an "underage child", so maybe that explains it, but I also get this feeling in general.

Is this some kind of actual law? That as soon as you touch a person physically, no matter in what context, "different rules apply"? That it somehow constitutes "an aggression"?

If somebody walked up to me with a damn phone camera filming my face and taunting me, I would be 100% within my moral rights to smack it off their hands, take it and throw it onto the ground, or even attack the person filming and taunting me. However, I'm sure this would not be *legally* allowed.

The person holding the camera is always like: "Don't you dare touch me, bro!", "Don't you f*****g touch the camera or you're going down!" or something like that.

I'm confused about how this situation could possibly develop. If "camera phones" had existed in the 1920s, the average man would more than likely "take a swing" at the person with the camera if they walked up and started spouting insults at them, possibly without any forewarning of any kind. That seems like the natural reaction to me, but all of that has completely changed, it seems.

It seems like these scumbags are legally allowed to just film others without their permission, follow them around, throw insults at them, and the victim isn't even allowed to *touch* the aggressor?

Comment: You say if someone filmed and taunted you, you'd assault them. So why do you have a hard time understanding why other people are going around assaulting people?

Comment: `I would be 100% within my moral rights to smack it off their hands, take it and throw it onto the ground, or even attack the person filming and taunting me.` .... and what makes you think this?  Are you claiming that you have a _moral right to attack someone because they insulted you_?  This is the first time I've ever heard of someone claiming a moral right to _attack_, as opposed to (possibly preemptively) _defend_.  Note that depending on situation you might not be charged, even if you were legally in the wrong, or convicted even if charged (jury nullification).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com

Comment: No - it is not moral or legal to respond to insulting by assaulting.

Comment: What, exactly, are "moral rights"?

Answer (score 0):

### Touching someone with intent to do harm is [battery](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(crime))

Not just in the United States but throughout the common law world including the UK, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, South Africa, Kenya etc.

Battery is often confused with [assault](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assault) which is the *threat* to commit battery.

These nations have decided that you are not allowed to hurt people or their things no matter how annoying they may or may not be. We find it reduces the amount of blood in the streets which really stains the concrete.

Comment: Assault may mean the act of causing injury. Kentucky defines it this way.  Menacing is used as the traditional "assault."